# Request specs for nested_attributes form using cocoon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

I am using Rails 4 with nested_attributes forms with the cocoon gem. This allows to add out of the box links to add a new element or remove it from the main class.

The problem is this gem when creating a new form does not give an unique identifier to the form.And I am trying to test it using Rspec, capybara and poltergeist.

Imagine the example I have an article that has many images and the respective views with the form to create it! here => https://gist.github.com/andreorvalho/5141c667a80be72edd5e
 and here => https://gist.github.com/andreorvalho/ca52e823a4930dac1a3c

The test fails with the following:

```
Failures:

  1) Article Admin creates a new article with more than one image
     Failure/Error: within_fieldset("image") do
     Capybara::Ambiguous:
       Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching fieldset "image"
     # ./spec/features/article_spec.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Obviously this happens because the id I gave them is the same and there is 2 forms and capybara cannot distinguish them, but does anybody know how I can do it?

Does cocoon have something implemented for this?

Do you know any other ways of testing it that would make sense?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this? maybe @nathanvda knows the answer?

Comment: I actually found a work around and will post an answer as soon as I can, but would be good if cocoon gave an helper for testing this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I end-up finding a work around:

```
within(all(:xpath, '//fieldset#image')[0]) do
  attach_file 'Image', test_image_path
  fill_in "Title", with: "My Article Image"
  fill_in "Description", with: "My Article Image Description"
  fill_in "Copyright", with: "My Article Image Copyright"
end
```

the all function returns an array with all the xpath for those requirments and then you can use it to iterate over it.